# Aggregating physical science data from multiple sources for time series

Tags: time-series, data-imputation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I’m attempting to build a time series model using water quality data. The problem is, for any given site where this data exists, it is irregular time intervals and sparse data (anywhere from 20-70% null values).

My idea was to aggregate several sites together in an attempt to have equi distant time intervals as well as less sparse data. However I realized that unless the sites are pretty much equivalent in the metrics, then aggregating won’t make any sense.

So my question is, is there a way to tell if sites x and y are similar enough to aggregate?
Also wondering what thoughts are on methods for imputation like interpolation.

Edit:
The data consists of various water quality measurements like: phosphorus/nitrogen levels, dissolved oxygen, chlorophyll a, water temp, etc. The model is trying to predict dissolved oxygen x days in the future. The raw data is arranged such that each row represents an individual sample, so it includes the parameter (ie what was measured) the result value of the measurement, timestamp (there may be several timestamps for a given day), and location.

Comment: Can you give us some more information about what you plan on doing with the time series model, and what your data are? Are these timestamped measurements of multiple variables, with different intervals between successive samples?

Comment: See edit, thanks